# Template function "Subscript requires array type", but works in smaller projects. Why?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, subscript

The following code is part of an interpolation function I wrote as part of a larger project.  The first version of this function returned the myScalar yval, but I modified it to return a flag on whether or not the function worked.

My question is this.  The following code compiles when run by itself both on codepad.org and in a smaller Visual Studio project.  In my larger project, though, I am getting error C2109 "subscript requires array or pointer type."  What could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance! -- Joe

```
using namespace std;

template <class myScalar, class myXVec, class myYVec>
int finterp(int mode, myXVec xarray, myYVec yarray, int num_pts, myScalar xval, myScalar &yval)
{
   myScalar dx, dydx, xmin, xmax;
   int success_flag = 0;

   if (num_pts < 1) return success_flag;
   yval = yarray[0]; //Visual Studio error C2109

   //some more calculations are here

   success_flag = 1;
   return success_flag;
}

int main()
{
   double *xvec, *yvec;
   xvec = new double [5]; yvec = new double [5];
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      xvec[i] = (double)i;
      yvec[i] = (double)i+1;
   }
   double x, y;
   x = 3.0;
   int success = finterp(1, xvec, yvec, 5, x, y);
   cout << y << "  " << success << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1> j:\london_study\irasshell_2011-05-13\iras_src\templateutilityfunctions.h(74): 
   error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
1> j:\london_study\irasshell_2011-05-13\iras_src\hydpowclass.cpp(41) : 
   see reference to function template instantiation 'int finterp<double,std::vector<_Ty>,double>(int,myXVec,myYVec,int,myScalar,myScalar &)' being compiled 
1> with 
1> [ 
1> _Ty=double, 
1> myXVec=std::vector<double>,
1> myYVec=double, 
1> myScalar=double 
1> ]
```

Comment: Which line does the error message indicate is the problem?

Comment: The one commented as error c2109, yval = yarray[0]

Comment: @Joe : Ah, sorry, I'm not fully awake yet :-P

Comment: I don't see any problem. Most certainly the problem is somewhere else, or you didn't quote the code properly.

Comment: @ildjarn no problem! :-) I can realize why an assignment like that would be ambiguous, but I don't know why this code is working in a small project but not in my bigger project.  Am I doing something dangerous that is making the function unstable?  I haven't used templates much before this project.

Comment: seems to compile fine on gcc version 4.3.2

Comment: @Joe : MSVC should show the types of `myScalar`, `myXVec` and `myYVec` for that particular instantiation of `finterp<>` in the Output window when the error occurs. What types does it say they are?

Comment: At compile time, does the compiler check all instances of the template function?

Comment: Oh because it looks like somewhere else I am calling finterp but not giving YVec an array or vector....

Comment: @Joe : Function templates are not actually functions (and likewise for non-explicitly-specialized template classes), merely patterns for the compiler to substitute real types into during compilation; after type substitution has occurred, compilation continues as normal so you end up getting errors specific to the template argument types used in that particular instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, in your real code a mere `double` is being passed in for `yarray` rather than a `double*` or `std::vector<double>`. This is a simple case of having a sufficiently small, but incorrect, repro -- the real error lies in your real code.

Comment: Thanks so much to ildjarn and others for your help! I learned more in 3 minutes on this site interacting with you all than in many other minutes reading other places. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've posted, you're calling `finterp` with `myYVec = double*`.  This can be indexed just fine with `[0]`.

When you use this in a larger project, how are you calling `finterp`?  Visual Studio should tell you in the error messages after the c2109.

Whatever type you're passing in as the third parameter is apparently non-indexable.

**EDIT**  Ah, you've updated your question with the error message.  The error occurs when you call `finterp` with `myYVec = double` -- which is NOT indexable.  I think you meant to use a `double*`.